# Difference between c and java on simple array functions?

Tags: java, arrays, c

Besides some obvious difference like difference [] placement, are there any fundamental difference between array in java and in c?

I wrote small program that calculates sum to compare them.

```
//java
public static int arraySum(int[] a) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++) {
            sum = sum + a[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] tryArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
        System.out.println(arraySum(tryArray));
    }
```

```
//c
int sum_array(int a[], int len) {
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
sum += a[i];
}
return sum;
}
int main(void) {
int my_array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
trace_int(sum_array(my_array, 5)); // any ways to remove the 5(length) from the parameter?
}
```

Also, if I use char arrays in c, it looks like string in java? `char posi_string[3] = "str"`

Can I use this method to manipulate string in c?

Comment: Also something to note, `char posi_string[3] = "str"` is _not_ a good idea as C style strings require a null terminator or `\0` to work with the various standard library functions. So you should do `char posi_string[4] = "str"` or `char posi_string[4] = "str\0"` for better understanding.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 do I need to leave an extra index for every array? for example, should I make the `int my_array[5]` in the above sum function into `int my_array[6]`?

Comment: Nope, just for C style strings. The NULL terminator is vital in a C-style string, and example why is the `strlen` function, which goes through the string until it can find `\0` and then returns the length of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ways to remove the length from the parameter?

**No.** When you pass an array to a function in C, it is no longer assumed as an array but a pointer. Since it's a pointer, you can no longer evaluate its size with `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` – thus, you just need to pass another parameter, for example, `size` to tell the array size to the function.

> If I use char arrays in C, does it looks like a string in Java?

**No.** Java has a `String` class that is rich in built-in code. Unlikely in C, `char` is a primitive data type, and it has no functions, you need to create one manually.